# Анимация WPF при изменении свойства

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация, property

Есть класс, представляющий игрока (привожу упрощенный вариант):

```
class Player : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; }

    int rank;
    public int Rank
    {
        get
        {
            return rank;
        }
        set
        {
            rank = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Rank"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Player(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Коллекция этих Players отображается, ну скажем, в ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl Name="icPlayers">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Margin="0,2.5" Padding="5"
                    BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkBlue">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneTime}" FontWeight="Bold"/>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Рейтинг:" Margin="0,0,3,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Rank, Mode=OneWay}" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Внешние силы меняют рейтинг игрока (не часто, не чаще 1 раза в несколько секунд).

Можно ли сделать средствами анимации WPF (не принципиально) так, чтобы при изменении рейтинга число в TextBox'е менялось плавно от текущего значения до нового, ну скажем, за 0.2 секунды?

Я могу, конечно, в сеттере запускать таймер, но это решение мне не нравится.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такой фичи из коробки нету, но её можно легко смастерить самостоятельно. Например, давайте заведём для этого attached property.

```
public static class AnimatableDoubleHelper
{
    // Это attached property OriginalProperty. К нему мы будем привязывать свойство из VM,
    // и получать нотификацию об его изменении
    public static double GetOriginalProperty(DependencyObject obj) =>
        (double)obj.GetValue(OriginalPropertyProperty);
    public static void SetOriginalProperty(DependencyObject obj, double value) =>
        obj.SetValue(OriginalPropertyProperty, value);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OriginalPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "OriginalProperty", typeof(double), typeof(AnimatableDoubleHelper),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnOriginalUpdated));

    // это "производное" attached property, которое будет
    // анимированно "догонять" OriginalProperty
    public static double GetAnimatedProperty(DependencyObject obj) =>
        (double)obj.GetValue(AnimatedPropertyProperty);
    public static void SetAnimatedProperty(DependencyObject obj, double value) =>
        obj.SetValue(AnimatedPropertyProperty, value);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AnimatedPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "AnimatedProperty", typeof(double), typeof(AnimatableDoubleHelper));

    // это вызывается когда значение OriginalProperty меняется
    static void OnOriginalUpdated(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double newValue = (double)e.NewValue;
        // находим элемент, на котором меняется свойство
        FrameworkElement self = (FrameworkElement)o;
        DoubleAnimation animation = // создаём анимацию...
            new DoubleAnimation(newValue, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3)));
        // и запускаем её на AnimatedProperty
        self.BeginAnimation(AnimatedPropertyProperty, animation);
    }
}
```

Как этим пользоваться? Очень просто. Пусть у нас был такой код:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Rank, StringFormat=0}"/>
```

Заменяем его на следующую конструкцию:

```
<TextBlock local:AnimatableDoubleHelper.OriginalProperty="{Binding Rank}"
           Text="{Binding (local:AnimatableDoubleHelper.AnimatedProperty),
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                          StringFormat=0}"/>
```

Получается вот что:

[image: все любят анимашки!]

Comment: VladD, а чем вы делаете такие gif-ки? (если не секрет, конечно).

Comment: то что надо, спасибо!

Comment: @BlackWitcher: Я забил в гугл «gif screencast windows free», и в первых результатах оказался [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/a/657800/56347), а он привёл меня на LICEcap. Таких же по функциональности программ ещё море.

Comment: @Андрей: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло.

Comment: @VladD, в том и дело, что море ) Спасибо!

Comment: @VladD, а как поступить, если требуется анимировать несколько свойств, например, координаты `Left` и `Top`? Заводить 2 класса с одинаковым функционалом не хочется

Comment: @Андрей: ну, по-разному можно. Например, можно заменить `double` на `Point`, и `DoubleAnimation` на [`PointAnimation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.pointanimation(v=vs.110).aspx). Можно завести вспомогательный невидимый `UIElement`, и навесить второй экземпляр `AnimatableDoubleHelper` на него.

Comment: @VladD, так и не получилось у меня использовать `PointAnimation` - не понятно как потом из этой `Point` `DependencyProperty` извлечь `X` и `Y` в разметке чтобы забиндить их на `Left` и `Top`. А второй вариант вообще не понятно как использовать в том примере. Можете набросать пример применительно к этому ответу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/699504/218063

Comment: @Андрей: вот тут изменения: https://pastebin.com/q9fHdvRq

Comment: @VladD Благодарю за ваш способ анимации объектов. Использую ваши классы для реализации своей команды и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть 2 кнопки, которые запускают одну и туже анимацию. При клике и работы анимации первой кнопки, я могу с легкостью кликнуть на вторую кнопку и параллельно первой анимации запустить другую. Можете посоветовать как с MVVM и такими классами исправить эту проблему?

Comment: @Dominik: И сразу вопрос: а какой _смысл_ анимации? От ответа на этот вопрос зависит правильный метод.