# Как по координатам найти объект на Canvas'е и переместить его?

Tags: c#, wpf

На интерфейсе располагается в центре кнопка, вокруг него элементы типа Image. С виду это выглядит как квадрат 3 на 3. При клике на кнопку окружающие картинки должны сместится на одну клетку при каждом клике. Например, картинка которая находится (объясняю на языке двухмерного массива), которая располагается на позиции 1 0 от кнопки, должна сместится на позицию 0 0, а другая картинка с позиции 0 0, на позицию 0 1.

При помощи такого подхода:

```
image10.BeginAnimation(MarginProperty, new ThicknessAnimation
{
    From = new Thickness(99, 66, 361, 212),
    To = new Thickness(99, 24, 361, 254),
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.85)
});
```

мне удается выполнить такое действие до второго клика. После второго клика картинки возвращаются в начальные положения и повторяют действие первого клика, а нужно чтобы при каждом клике ничего не сбивалось и картинки перемещались по кругу.
Чтобы реализовать такой подход, я понял, что строго к элементам обращаться не получится, ибо выходит то, что написал выше.
Поэтому вопрос таков, как при помощи координат в коде C# мне обратится к объекту, который располагается в данном месте и анимированно переместить в другое место?
Как я прочитал в интернете для поиска и перемещения нужно, чтобы все объекты располагались на канвасе. Однако скажу сразу, что я пытался при помощи такого подхода получить координаты.

```
Canvas.SetLeft(image10, 0);
Canvas.SetTop(image10, 0);
```

Но при помощи такого подхода не выходит прицепить анимацию перемещения, а она очень важна.

P.S. Буду признателен, если озвучите более просто подход выполнения этой задумки.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Давайте напишем класс, представляющий "плитку":

```
class Tile : Vm
{
    int x;
    public int X
    {
        get => x;
        set => Set(ref x, value);
    }

    int y;
    public int Y
    {
        get => y;
        set => Set(ref y, value);
    }

    string caption;
    public string Caption
    {
        get => caption;
        set => Set(ref caption, value);
    }
}
```

Вы в своем классе будете хранить картинку или ссылку на нее, я использую просто строковую надпись `string Caption`

Теперь главная `ViewModel`:

```
class MainVM : Vm
{
    ObservableCollection<Tile> tiles;
    public ObservableCollection<Tile> Tiles
    {
        get => tiles;
        set => Set(ref tiles, value);
    }

    RelayCommand turnCommand;
    public ICommand TurnCommand => turnCommand;

    public MainVM()
    {
        Tiles = new ObservableCollection<Tile>
        {
            new Tile { Caption="1", X = 0, Y = 0 },
            new Tile { Caption="2", X = 1, Y = 0 },
            new Tile { Caption="3", X = 2, Y = 0 },
            new Tile { Caption="4", X = 2, Y = 1 },
            new Tile { Caption="5", X = 2, Y = 2 },
            new Tile { Caption="6", X = 1, Y = 2 },
            new Tile { Caption="7", X = 0, Y = 2 },
            new Tile { Caption="8", X = 0, Y = 1 },
        };

        turnCommand = new RelayCommand(_ => TurnTiles());
    }

    void TurnTiles()
    {
        // Здесь используются фичи C# 7.0 и .NET Framework 4.7
        Dictionary<(int, int), (int, int)> transitions = new Dictionary<(int, int), (int, int)>
        {
            [(0, 0)] = (0, 1),
            [(1, 0)] = (0, 0),
            [(2, 0)] = (1, 0),
            [(2, 1)] = (2, 0),
            [(2, 2)] = (2, 1),
            [(1, 2)] = (2, 2),
            [(0, 2)] = (1, 2),
            [(0, 1)] = (0, 2),
        };
        foreach (var tile in Tiles)
            (tile.X, tile.Y) = transitions[(tile.X, tile.Y)];
        /* Вариант "по-старинке", для тех, у кого по каким-то причинам не работает вариант выше
        Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Tuple<int, int>> transitions = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Tuple<int, int>>
        {
            [Tuple.Create(0, 0)] = Tuple.Create(0, 1),
            [Tuple.Create(1, 0)] = Tuple.Create(0, 0),
            [Tuple.Create(2, 0)] = Tuple.Create(1, 0),
            [Tuple.Create(2, 1)] = Tuple.Create(2, 0),
            [Tuple.Create(2, 2)] = Tuple.Create(2, 1),
            [Tuple.Create(1, 2)] = Tuple.Create(2, 2),
            [Tuple.Create(0, 2)] = Tuple.Create(1, 2),
            [Tuple.Create(0, 1)] = Tuple.Create(0, 2),
        };
        foreach (var tile in Tiles)
        {
            var coords = transitions[Tuple.Create(tile.X, tile.Y)];
            tile.X = coords.Item1;
            tile.Y = coords.Item2;
        }
        */
    }
}
```

В общем-то все просто, коллекция с "плитками" и команда для их перемещения по кругу. Причем в этом примере использовать `ObservableCollection` даже не обязательно, вы можете использовать обычный `List`.
`transitions` - это словарь переходов, ключ словаря - начальные координаты плитки, значение - конечные

Теперь займемся представлением.
Напишем конвертеры координат `VM` => `View`:

```
class XToLeftConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public double TileWidth { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value * TileWidth;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

И

```
class YToTopConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public double TileHeight { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value * TileHeight;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

В них определено публичное свойство, которое будет устанавливаться из разметки.

Теперь сама разметка окна, в качестве примера я использовал [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/508647/218063):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainVM}"
        mc:Ignorable="d" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="400">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:XToLeftConverter x:Key="XToLeftConverter" TileWidth="100"/>
        <local:YToTopConverter x:Key="YToTopConverter" TileHeight="100"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="5"> 
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Height="99" Width="99"
                            BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"
                            Value="{Binding X, Converter={StaticResource XToLeftConverter}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"
                            Value="{Binding Y, Converter={StaticResource YToTopConverter}}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>

        <Button Content="Rotate" Command="{Binding TurnCommand}"
                Width="99" Height="99" Margin="100,100,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Немного кривовато, но пока так.
В принципе это уже работает, но, пока, без анимации. При клике по кнопке в центре плитки перепрыгивают по кругу.

Теперь это все дело нужно анимировать, я использовал [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/583262/218063). Я пока не знаю, как использовать этот класс-хелпер для анимации двух свойств, поэтому завел два класса с одинаковым содержимым (как появится информация - обновлю ответ): `AnimatableLeftHelper` и `AnimatableTopHelper`.
Теперь используем эти хелперы чтобы анимировать свойства:

```
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="local:AnimatableLeftHelper.OriginalProperty"
                            Value="{Binding X, Converter={StaticResource XToLeftConverter}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"
                            Value="{Binding (local:AnimatableLeftHelper.AnimatedProperty), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="local:AnimatableTopHelper.OriginalProperty"
                            Value="{Binding Y, Converter={StaticResource YToTopConverter}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"
                            Value="{Binding (local:AnimatableTopHelper.AnimatedProperty), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                </Style>
```

Готово!

[image: RotateTiles]

Здесь я использовал "стандартные" классы для `MVVM` `WPF`
`Vm`:

```
abstract class Vm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;
        field = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

`RelayCommand`:

```
class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    protected readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    protected readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, _ => true) { }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        _canExecute = canExecute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(canExecute));
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

---

[Благодаря помощи @VladD'а](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583124/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-wpf-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0/583262#comment1039564_583262) удалось переписать пример с использованием `PointAnimation`:

"Плитка":

```
class Tile : Vm
{
    Point coords;
    public Point Coords
    {
        get => coords;
        set => Set(ref coords, value);
    }

    string caption;
    public string Caption
    {
        get => caption;
        set => Set(ref caption, value);
    }
}
```

Главная `VM`:

```
class MainVM : Vm
{
    ObservableCollection<Tile> tiles;
    public ObservableCollection<Tile> Tiles
    {
        get => tiles;
        set => Set(ref tiles, value);
    }

    public ICommand TurnCommand { get; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        Tiles = new ObservableCollection<Tile>
        {
            new Tile { Caption="1", Coords = new Point(0, 0) },
            new Tile { Caption="2", Coords = new Point(1, 0) },
            new Tile { Caption="3", Coords = new Point(2, 0) },
            new Tile { Caption="4", Coords = new Point(2, 1) },
            new Tile { Caption="5", Coords = new Point(2, 2) },
            new Tile { Caption="6", Coords = new Point(1, 2) },
            new Tile { Caption="7", Coords = new Point(0, 2) },
            new Tile { Caption="8", Coords = new Point(0, 1) }
        };

        TurnCommand = new DelegateCommand(_ => TurnTiles());
    }

    void TurnTiles()
    {
        Dictionary<Point, Point> transitions = new Dictionary<Point, Point>
        {
            [new Point(0, 0)] = new Point(0, 1),
            [new Point(1, 0)] = new Point(0, 0),
            [new Point(2, 0)] = new Point(1, 0),
            [new Point(2, 1)] = new Point(2, 0),
            [new Point(2, 2)] = new Point(2, 1),
            [new Point(1, 2)] = new Point(2, 2),
            [new Point(0, 2)] = new Point(1, 2),
            [new Point(0, 1)] = new Point(0, 2),
        };
        foreach (var tile in Tiles)
            tile.Coords = transitions[tile.Coords];
    }
}
```

Конвертер всего один теперь:

```
class XYToPointConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public double TileWidth { get; set; }
    public double TileHeight { get; set; }
    public double LeftOffset { get; set; }
    public double TopOffset { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var typedValue = (Point)value;
        return new Point(typedValue.X * TileWidth + LeftOffset, typedValue.Y * TileHeight + TopOffset);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Я добавил в него еще пару свойств со смещениями, чтобы настраивать положение плиток можно было более гибко.

Разметка окна:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainVM, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        mc:Ignorable="d" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="400">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:XYToPointConverter x:Key="XYToPointConverter"
                                  TileWidth="100" TileHeight="100"
                                  LeftOffset="0" TopOffset="0"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="5">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Height="99" Width="99"
                            BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="local:AnimatablePointHelper.OriginalProperty"
                            Value="{Binding Coords, Converter={StaticResource XYToPointConverter}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"
                            Value="{Binding (local:AnimatablePointHelper.AnimatedProperty).X, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"
                            Value="{Binding (local:AnimatablePointHelper.AnimatedProperty).Y, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>

        <Button Content="Rotate" Command="{Binding TurnCommand}"
                Width="99" Height="99" Margin="100,100,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Ну и класс-хелпер для анимации:

```
static class AnimatablePointHelper
{
    public static Point GetOriginalProperty(DependencyObject obj) =>
        (Point)obj.GetValue(OriginalPropertyProperty);
    public static void SetOriginalProperty(DependencyObject obj, Point value) =>
        obj.SetValue(OriginalPropertyProperty, value);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OriginalPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "OriginalProperty", typeof(Point), typeof(AnimatablePointHelper),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnOriginalUpdatedStatic));

    public static Point GetAnimatedProperty(DependencyObject obj) =>
        (Point)obj.GetValue(AnimatedPropertyProperty);
    public static void SetAnimatedProperty(DependencyObject obj, Point value) =>
        obj.SetValue(AnimatedPropertyProperty, value);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AnimatedPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "AnimatedProperty", typeof(Point), typeof(AnimatablePointHelper));

    static void OnOriginalUpdatedStatic(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Point newValue = (Point)e.NewValue;
        FrameworkElement self = (FrameworkElement)o;
        AnimationTimeline animation =
            new PointAnimation(newValue, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3)));
        self.BeginAnimation(AnimatedPropertyProperty, animation);
    }
}
```

Результат тот же.

Comment: " // Здесь используются фичи C# 7.0 и .NET Framework 4.7"
Перевел свой проект на 4.7 .NET и 7 шарп, но все равно ругается на эту конструкцию. Можно ли ее как-то упростить, чтобы компилятор пропустил?

Comment: @Dominik: А как именно ругается?

Comment: @VladD Подчеркивает по всему словарю и foreach. Скорее всего из-за того, что каждый аргумент содержит по два аргумента и пишет "использование универсального тип Dictionary требует аргументы тип 2". foreach подчеркивает потому что из-за ошибки Dictionary метод не хочет правильно закрываться (все фигурные скобки на месте) и foreach не входит в состав класса.

Comment: @Dominik: А если откомпилировать, какое _первое_ сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: @VladD не показывает точно, но по всему проекту ошибки только в этом словаре.

Comment: @Dominik: Что означает «не показывает точно»? Вы смотрите список ошибок компиляции или Intellisense? Смотрите список ошибок компиляции.

Comment: @VladD Серьезность Код Описание Проект Файл Строка
Ошибка CS1525 Недопустимый термин "int" в выражении WpfApplication3 C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WpfApplication3\WpfApplication3\ViewModel.cs 44

Comment: @Dominik: А что в этой строке?

Comment: @VladD Dictionary < (int, int), (int, int)> transitions = new Dictionary<(int, int), (int, int)>
Я же говорил, по всему словарю.

Comment: @Dominik: А какая версия студии? 2017?

Comment: @VladD 2015 стоит

Comment: @Dominik: А, понятно. Тогда нужно даунгрейдить версию языка. Попробуйте заменить `(int, int)` на `Tuple<int, int>`, но там понадобится исправить и другие ошибки компиляции, которые произойдут из-за замены.

Comment: @VladD Помогло. Но как быть с присвоением начиная отсюда "[(0, 0)] = (0, 1),"?
Там каков синтаксис будет?

Comment: @Dominik: `(0, 0)` -> `Tuple.Create(0, 0)` и т. д.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Да, удалось. Логика работы мне ясна, сейчас по своей задумке стараюсь расширить работу. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @users, отступы выставлены намеренно, для того чтобы был виден уровень вложенности. Это улучшает читаемость, так как чуть выше указан фрагмент кода в который дальше вносятся корректировки

Comment: @Dominik, дополнил ответ