# Кнопка UncheckAll в заголовке datagridcheckboxcolumn

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

Как сделать кнопку в заголовке datagridcheckboxcolumn, которая убирает все галочки в колонке?
Саму кнопку я размещаю определяя шаблон заголовка столбца таблицы.

```
 <!--Style for Checkbox column Header-->
 <Style x:Key="CheckBoxColumnHeader" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource DGridCentAl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Grid x:Name="Root">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Viewbox Height="17" Grid.Row="1">
                        <Path Fill="#7F7F7F" 
                              Data="M0 29692l5358 0 0 -13577 -5358 0 0 13577zm6722 8l5402 0 0 -29700 -5402 0 0 29700zm6760 0l5402 0 0 -20258 -5402 0 0 20258z"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <Viewbox Height="8" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0 0 0 -11" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Grid>
                            <Button Background="Transparent" x:Name="btn_UncheckedAll">
                                <Polygon Fill="#F79646" 
                                         Points="0,418 418,0 1463,1045 2508,0 2996,418 1881,1463 2996,2509 2508,2996 1463,1881 418,2996 0,2509 1045,1463 "/>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                        </Viewbox>
                    <!--Vertical border-->
                    <StackPanel x:Name="VerticalSeparator" Grid.RowSpan="3" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="1" Visibility="Visible" Fill="#FFF"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <!--Без этой штуки отрисовывается левая граница ячейки не разобрался почему. Нарисовал белую поверх-->
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Получается вот такой заголовок. По нажатию на оранжевый крестик необходимо убрать все поставленные галочки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите на английском stackoverflaw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208004/datagrid-column-header-should-check-uncheck-checkbox-s-state-depending-upon-wh

Comment: Измените шаблон заголовка этого столбца. А флажки... Используйте MVVM, это решится очевидным путем

Comment: Вам непонятно как разместить кнопку в заголовке DataGrid или как снять все флажки при клике по ней?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, вы в своем `DataGrid` отображаете некую коллекцию `MyItems`, которая содержит в себе некие элементы `MyItem`:

```
public class MyItem
{
    ...

    public bool MyBoolProp { get { ... } set { ... } }

    ...
}
```

При этом класс `MyItem` должен реализовать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged` (INPC) чтобы оповещать View об изменении свойств.

Если вы используете подход MVVM, то вам нужно создать команду для снятия флажков:

```
public ICommand UncheckAllCommand { get; }
```

и в конструкторе VM записать в нее вызов метода:

```
UncheckAllCommand = new MyCommand(_ => UnckeckAll());
```

Сам метод может выглядеть как-то так:

```
void UnckeckAll()
{
    foreach (var item in MyItems)
        item.MyBoolProp = false;
}
```

Пример реализации интерфейса команды и INPC можно посмотреть, например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/699504/218063).

---

Если вы ничего не знаете и не хотите знать про MVVM, то можете просто подписаться на событие клика по кнопке:

```
<Button Background="Transparent" x:Name="btn_UncheckedAll"
        Click="btn_UncheckedAll_Click">
```

и в подписчике снять галочки:

```
public void btn_UncheckedAll_Click(...)
{
    foreach (var item in MyItems)
        item.MyBoolProp = false;
```

При этом, если ваш класс не реализует INPC, то нужно будет еще и вручную обновить представление:

```
    myDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
}
```