# Hyperlink в Frame

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть проект, который использует WpfUi, который требует, чтоб мы использовали `Frame` в качестве обертки над страницами. Ладно, я смирился с этим, лезть в дебри и переписывать не стал, но этот `Frame` подсовывает мне "свинью", которую не знаю как грамотно обойти.

Допустим есть главное окно, в котором прописано

```xml
<Frame Source="Page1.xaml" />
```

В `Page1` пишем такой код:

```xml
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="https://ru.stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Запускаем, видим ссылку

[image: Link]

Все вроде как надо, но нет.. Если нажать на нее, то `Frame` подхватит это, и начнет делать переход на этот сайт внутри фрейма, используя встроенный, старый движок IE.

[image: Frame Redirect]

**Вопрос:** Как запретить `Frame` перехватывать нажатие на подобные ссылки?

В реальном проекте все чуть запутанней, там при помощи `markdig.wpf` загружается Markdown документ в котором есть ссылки, ну и сам клик по ссылкам обрабатывается отдельным событием, которое открывает дефолтный браузер пользователя, и в это время фрейм грузит попутно и у себя данную ссылку, чего быть не должно...

Comment: А в э том hyperlink нельзя перехватить клик и отправить ссылку на shell execute, что бы винда дальше со ссылкой разбиралась?

Comment: @tym32167 У ссылки есть `RequestNavigate` событие, в котором можно установить `e.Handled = true`, и в нем сделать уже открытие ссылки с дефолтном браузере, работать будет, фрейм перестанет ловить ссылки. НО... В реальном проекте, как я и написал, все немного сложней, и мне придется переделывать конвертацию Markdown в XAML, ковырять исходники библиотеки, чтоб подписаться на это событие. Может есть альтернатива?

Comment: Навесить `Style` на все гиперлинки, [вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1524153/373567) смотрите как я стиль с `EventSetter` навесил.

Comment: @aepot Через стили да, может прокатить, попробую. Кроме этого варианта еще альтернативы есть какие либо?